# Does every single service on an OS listen to a port?

Tags: port

I know that

- On the one hand, we have normal applications that have a UI and the user directly interacts with them.
- On the other hand, we have **services** which run on the background of the OS, like `mysql` and `apache`, and do not have any UI (user does not interact with them as with normal applications). They get installed on the OS just like other applications.

Is this correct: "Every single service on an OS listens to at least one port."

Or in other words, do we have some services (e.g. on Windows) that **DO NOT** listen to a port?

Comment: This really isn't the right place to ask this question.

Comment: kindly tell me where should i ask it? thanks

Comment: Super User or Server Fault maybe. I'm not actually sure now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service is just a program. Is the program that listens on a port or not. Of course you can create a program that does not listens in any port and make it a service, ie a program to index your disk contents to speed up searches..

Comment: i assume that all web based services listen to a specific port right?

Comment: @varDumper I think that is implicit in your assumption of what a "web service" means.

Comment: yep, you're right. to be more specific have to say 'every single service that needs to communicate with other services (or applications or even computers) via any type of network as well  as the web, should listen to a port in order to do that. right?

Comment: Specifically, if you use TCP or UDP to communicate, yes, you need a port.

Comment: ok, that's more lucid, is there any other situation that would need a service to listen to a port?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for services to expose access through many means, including but not limited to:

- shared memory,
- ports,
- OS specific hooks and callbacks,
- and others...

"ports" are a relatively straight forward and cross-platform way to do so.